# Como parar uma stored procedures no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

existe a possibilidade de **parar** uma `stored procedures`no `MySQL`? Coloquei uma `procedures` para alimentar uma tabela de banco para testes de carga com 10 milhões de registros, porém a inserção está muito lenta e queria parar a mesma sem ter que parar o servidor (há outras aplicações rodando nele).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tente estabelecer uma nova conexão com o banco. Caso você tenha executado a chamada da `procedures` via `PHPMyAdmin` será necessário utilizar outro browser, ou fechar o atual completamente antes de tentar entrar no banco de dados novamente, pois o servidor reconhece que você ainda está "aguardando" receber a resposta a sua solicitação.

Execute o comando `SHOW PROCESSLIST` para ver os processos. encontre a sua Storege procedure que esta em execução e use o comando `KILL`.
Exemplo:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST; -- irá listar varios processos, veja o da sua procedure

KILL 749; -- no lugar do 749 coloque o ID do processo.
```